# Run TensorFlow on Macbook Pro 2016 with OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, opencl

My laptop is Macbook Pro 2016 with graphic card Radeon Pro 460.
Is there anyway that I can leverage my GPU to speed up tensorflow?

I understand that CUDA is for NVIDIA card, and CUDA version of TF doesn't work. Is there any other tool that I can use GPU to run TF such as OpenCL?

> Update: One potential answer is that: "You can run Tensorflow on a
>   Macbook Pro 2016 using tf-coriander . Disclosure: I'm the author. –
>   Hugh Perkins 2 days ago"

Comment: You can run Tensorflow on a Macbook Pro 2016 using [tf-coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander) . Disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: GREAT! can you put it as an answer, then other people can easily to see it

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you've read: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac

You cannot "trick your computer" and the suggestion that you might is perhaps contributing to your downvotes.

If you want to learn more about the *potential* to run TF on your current hardware have a look at the in-progress work being done on TF OpenCL (which supports AMD cards): https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorflow%20for%20opencl&rct=j that said, I think the OpenCL work for linux is much further along than for macos. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the openCL link.